# Paragon NTFS for Mac v12.1.62 shutting down computers, corrupting files

Tags: macos, mac, ntfs, osx-mountain-lion, paragon

We have Paragon NTFS for Mac 12.1.62 on seven Mac computers.  We've never had issues with Paragon for NTFS, but recently updated to version 12.1.62.  Ever since, we have had multiple problems with NTFS drives crashing our computers, and important files being corrupted as a result. Sometimes drives crash upon being mounted, other times crash just from moving files or folders, other times transferring files from one drive to another.

It does not freeze - the computers simply shut down without warning, and then restart with the message that "your computer was shut down because of a serious problem". This has happened with multiple different computers, some operating on Mac 10.8.5, others Mac 10.9.2.  Also happened with multiple different drives (Seagate, WD, Hitachi, etc.)  The only constant variable has been that all drives have been formatted using Paragon NTFS for Mac 12.1.62, and all the drives use USB-3. Any help greatly appreciated.  Would love to know if others are having the same problems.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact Paragon since that's the common link

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Same 12.1.62, but on OS X 10.10.1. Did you ever get it sorted?